# Intended compatibility of files contents while transition from 2.79->2.80->2.81

Tags: versions

I am working on a file, which is not my own and therefore cannot be posted -- and it is a really complicated one. This file, when loaded into Blender 2.81 crashes blender sooner or later. I inspected the crash-files and enabled debug mode and found some hints here and there.
I want to recreate the problem with a newly created file, which I can post. But before reporting, I want to make sure, that I am not reporting something, which cannot work.
The file was initially created with Blender 2.79 and still works with Blender 2.80. Loaded into Blender 2.81 it crashes Blender after a short time or freezes it.
What kind of compatibility is intended between these three versions of Blender?
(I know, that 2.81 is in its early stage... )

Comment: 2.81 is the current "stable" release, however Windows users have had some performance issues.  Which OS is this happening on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it crashes then it's a bug. Please report it on the [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/) (*Help > Report a Bug* in Blender). It would be ideal if you can create a .blend file that can be shared publicly.

You should be able to open and run 2.79 files in newer version with the exception of removed features such BGE or the Blender Internal render engine which no longer exist in 2.8 and beyond.

Comment: What is a reasonable way to figure out what of the bazillions of "things" in th original file may trigger the problem? Example: set "debug-fpe" results in myriads of debug prints onto the console (Linux) and I have to kill blender manually.

Comment: @mcc You may find a hint in the most basic log file (`--debug`), e.g. when there is a particular context where the crash occurs or when there are warnings. If it's completely unclear then create a copy of the project and delete objects etc. one by one and check if the crash still occurs. You don't have to find the source of the bug yourself, just a minimal blend file that causes the crash. The best approach would be to generate a stack trace using a debug build, however that require compiling Blender and setting up a debugger. Both needs some experience with software development.